# Several list into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 4 lists suchs as: l=[1,2,3....].I want to create a dictionary like this:

```
data={'a':[1,2,3...],'b':[4,5,6...]}
```

I've done this:

```
data={'a': x for x l,'b': x for x l'}
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `data = {'a' : list1, 'b' : list2}` would work fine. Your code doesn't even look like Python.

Comment: Thanks mate. It works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
data = {'a': l1, 'b': l2}
print data
```

Gives:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'a':l[0:3],'b':l[3:6]}
```

This should work. Break list using indexes

Answer (score 1):

If your lists are l1, l2, l3, l4, you can create the dictionary as

```
   data = {'a':l1, 'b':l2, 'c':l3, 'd': l4}
```